# pass the print function outcome into a list

Tags: python-3.x, taxonomy

I am experimenting with MISP taxonomies

```
!git clone https://github.com/MISP/PyTaxonomies
cd PyTaxonomies
!git submodule init && git submodule update
!python3 setup.py install
from pytaxonomies import Taxonomies
taxonomies = Taxonomies()
```

What I want is to pass the  print outcome inside a list

```
for i in taxonomies.values():
    print (i)
```

so I am trying the following:

```
taxonomies = []

for i in taxonomies.values():
    taxonomies.append(i)

taxonomies
```

However, I get back

```
[<pytaxonomies.api.Taxonomy at 0x7f67b1d86250>,
 <pytaxonomies.api.Taxonomy at 0x7f67ad048590>,
 <pytaxonomies.api.Taxonomy at 0x7f67b14f7b10>,
 <pytaxonomies.api.Taxonomy at 0x7f67b14f7550>,
.......
.......
 <pytaxonomies.api.Taxonomy at 0x7f67ac805290>,
 <pytaxonomies.api.Taxonomy at 0x7f67ac8052d0>,
 <pytaxonomies.api.Taxonomy at 0x7f67ac7ecc50>]
```

What I was expected to get back is the following:

```
[CERT-XLM:abusive-content="spam"
CERT-XLM:abusive-content="harmful-speech"
CERT-XLM:abusive-content="violence"
CERT-XLM:malicious-code="virus"
CERT-XLM:malicious-code="worm"
....
....
workflow:state="incomplete"
workflow:state="complete"
workflow:state="draft"
workflow:state="ongoing"
workflow:state="rejected"]
```

Any ideas to solve my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all be careful with the names of your variables, you repeated `taxonomies` tice which might destroy any data in your variable.
For your question, that is pretty normal giving that the list's values types are 'taxonomy' types, you just have to cast them to a string before. Here's a little example (I also changed a it a little using list comprehension to get a shorter version of the code) :

```
from pytaxonomies import Taxonomies

# fetching taxonomies
taxonomies = Taxonomies()

# casts the taxonomies output as a string before saving it in a list
taxonomies_out = [str(tax).replace('\n', ' ') for tax in taxonomies.values()]
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: hi, @mrCopiCat thank you for your answer. However, if you print taxonomies_out you get an extremely messy output very different from my desired output

Comment: it is pretty normal, because you are printing a list, so the list becomes the string when printing (in that case all its data is not considered as a string literal, which prevents interpreting `\n` the back to line. to print its values, just loop a print over them (works also without the cast mentioned before) `for t in taxonomies_out : print(t)`

Comment: to get every line separately in your list, you can use a `.split('\n')`  after your cast

Comment: Yes that's nice  howewer I want an outcome like this: taxonomies_out=[CERT-XLM:abusive-content="spam"
CERT-XLM:abusive-content="harmful-speech"
CERT-XLM:abusive-content="violence"
CERT-XLM:malicious-code="virus"
CERT-XLM:malicious-code="worm"
....
....
workflow:state="incomplete"
workflow:state="complete"
workflow:state="draft"
workflow:state="ongoing"
workflow:state="rejected"]

So after that to cast the information in pandas dataframe. To print the iterator of the list is not useful

Comment: then use the `replace ` method. I edited the code to fit your need.